# Why I can't assign dynamic data in constructor C#?

Tags: c#, php, reflection, constructor

I'm a PHP Developer...
I need to do a class that can be created and fill of dynamic way, similar to this in PHP.

```
class Person{
    private $name;
    private $age;

    function __construct($params = array()){
        foreach ($this as $key => $val) {
            $this -> $key = (isset($params[$key])) ? $params[$key] : "";
        }
    }

    function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    function getAge(){
        return $this->age;
    }

    function setName($value){
        $this->name = $value;
    }

    function setAge($value){
        $this->age = $value;
    }
}
```

I read about the reflection in C#, but I don't find the correct way to do.
This is my C# code

```
public class Person
{
    private String _name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
    private int _age { get { return _age; } set { _age = value; } }
    public Person()
    {

    }

    public Person(Hashtable _data)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
        propertyInfos = typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var propInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            typeof(Person).GetProperty(propInfo.Name).SetValue(this, _data[propInfo.Name]);
        }
    }
}
```

In runtime I get an Exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The typeof(Person) I try to change it to this.getType() and I get the same.

I hope that can help me.

Comment: You're property setters call themselves...forever.  You don't want to define your properties that way.  You should also be using `Dictionary` and not `HashTable`.  `HashTable` became obsolete when .NET 2.0 came out.

Comment: Better use a `IDictionary<string, object>`. `Hashtable` is the old .NET 1.0 stuff. Also, for private members you can use fields instead of properties.

Comment: Also there's no point in getting a property info and then asking the type for the property with that property info's name to get back the same property info.  You already had the property info, just use it.

Comment: thank you for a fast answer, I'll change the Hashtable for dictionary, but I don't understand why is the problem with the setters

Comment: `_name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }` - you will get infinite recursive call here, and StackOverflow exception as a result.

Comment: Okay, I ignored that you mention Yura. MSDN says that is the way to place getters and setters, I see it was not quite right.

Comment: Try adding a null check on _data before you use it.  Also add a check to _data for the key.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are grabbing all properties on the object and then looking them up in the hashtable.  You likely want the reverse--all objects in the hashtable set to properties on the object.  Otherwise you'll get an exception when you don't specify every single member.

As Alexei points out, the NullReferenceException is due to the second call to GetProperties only returning public properties when no BindingFlags are supplied.  Since there are no public properties, you get an exception.

Because C# is strongly typed, you run into a number of issues you don't have in PHP.  These include setting a value with an object of a type that doesn't match or convert to the property type, entries in your data parameter that don't exist as properties, etc.  I've done my best to document the gotchas I see below.

Here is what the Person class would look like (I've cleaned up some of the style and used classes to make it feel more like a C# class):

```
public class Person
{
    private string name { get; set; }
    private int age { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {

    }

    public Person(IDictionary<string,object> data)
    {
        foreach (var value in data)
        {
            // The following line will be case sensitive.  Do you need to standardize the case of the input dictionary before getting the property?
            PropertyInfo property = typeof(Person).GetProperty(value.Key, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (property != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(this, value.Value); // You are allowing any old object to be set here, so be prepared for conversion and casting exceptions
            }
            else
            {
                // How do you want to handle entries that don't map to properties?  Ignore?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an example of usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var person = new Person(new Dictionary<string,object>() {{"name" ,"Mike"}, {"age", 32}});
}
```

Comment: Code is correct, but I believe explanation of NRE is backward :) (NRE is really because of `GetProperty` returns only public properties if binding flags are not specified).

Comment: Thank you, your code is very useful to me. I'll implement two overloads one it's with Dictionary and other with Hasstables.

Your code it's the better way to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should stay away from using `var` if you're new to the language, it only complicates things.

The `propInfo` in your foreach-loop already is a `PropertyInfo`, so you don't need to find it again:

```
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(Person).GetProperties(flags);
foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in propertyInfos)
{
    propInfo.SetValue(this, _data[propInfo.Name]);
}
```

The `NullReferenceException` is probably caused by the following part of your original code:

```
typeof(Person).GetProperty(propInfo.Name)...
```

Since no `BindingFlags` are provided to the `GetProperty()` this time, it looks for public instance properties, and when no such property is found, it returns `null` (that, or `_data` is `null` to begin with).

As others have pointed out, your properties currently will cause `StackOverflowException`s. Try changing them to:

```
private String _name { get; set; }
private int _age { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering why you would want to do this. There may be better, more idiomatic C#, designs to achieve the behavior you want. But we can't know that because there is no additional contextual information mentioned in the question.

So I will simply try to answer your question. The version below takes your code,  using auto properties, and a simple dictionary lookup for the initialization of its members from the supplied dictionary. Also note that this does not require any reflection, because there is nothing `dynamic` about the members of this class.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Person(IDictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        // What to do if the map does not contain "Name" or "Age" ?
        // Right now: initialize to default value.
        Name = TryLookup<string>(data, "Name", null);
        Age = TryLookup<int>(data, "Age", default(int));
        // What to do if the map contains other items that do not
        // map to a member variable?
    }

    private static T TryLookup<T>(IDictionary<string, object> data, string key, T defaultValue)
    {
        return data.ContainsKey(key) ? (T)data[key] : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

In case you actually really really badly need a dynamic type as opposed to a statically defined type with fixed member properties, you could use an [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx%20ExpandoObject) or alternatively (but this is far from trivial) build a dynamic type using an [AssemblyBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20AssemblyBuilder) with a [TypeBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20TypeBuilder)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed not think I need a dynamic type is what I am escaping in PHP